How important is outlier clearing
When I'm doing data pre-processing , I always handle outlier, whether its using mean, median , and sometimes deleting it. But i realize that sometimes handling it just makes the accuracy lower, so i was wondering if it was actually important . If it doesn't, what other factors are important statistically, or non statistically in determining the accuracy of a model.
Some thought that i have been thinking of is stuff like feature creator where i make a new attributes based off my understanding, however, it wasn't enough to enhance the accuracy to the maximum point in comparison to others.
Therefore, I was wondering if anyone have similar problem and has met the solution for it.
